# Failed to restart isc-dhcp-server.service: Unit isc-dhcp-server.service is masked

Tags: networking, server, dhcp

Basically we follow this [guideline](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/isc-dhcp-server) to setup dhcp server. We downloaded isc-dhcp-server in Ubuntu. After we changed the `/etc/dhcpd/dhcp.conf`, we restart dhcp server by entering `sudo service isc-dhcp-server restart`, and it generates the following message:

```
Failed to restart isc-dhcp-server.service: Unit isc-dhcp-server.service is masked.
```

What does this error mean? We at least need to find out where the log is. Any sort of hints is appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot start the isc-dhcp-server beacuse the systemctl marked it as 'masked'. Masked is an advanced 'flag' similar of 'disabled'. Masking a service is a permanent change, much like disabling a service.

Look at **systemctl list-units**